# Sed does not replace in jenkins when using variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, sed

Im running shell scripts in jenkins as below (Change to groovy format). But when I try to run in jenkins it did not replace the value for **port_https**. However, when I tried to run manually is change the value as exported.

```
 sh "find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec sed -i -e \"s/url_protocol: http\$/url_protocol: https/g\" {} \\ ;"sh "find ./ -type f -name '*.yml' -exec sed -i -e \'s/protocol: \"http\"\$/protocol: \"https\"/g\' {} \\;"sh "export abc_port=\"\$(find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/abc1/vars.yml -exec grep abc_solution_portbase: {} \\; | cut -d: -f2)\" ; export port_https=\$((\$abc_port + 81)) ; export port=\"\$(find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/def1/vars.yml -exec sh -c 'grep -A 3 -e def_nei_abc_host {} | grep -e port' \\; | cut -d: -f2)\" ; find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/def1/vars.yml -exec sed -i -e 's/port:\${port}/port: \"\"\${port_https}\"\"/g' {} \\;"
```

The console output shows the correct exported value for each parameter.

Update:

The line that have the problem

```
find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/def1/vars.yml -exec sed -i -e 's/port: "24080"$/port: 24081/g' '{}' ';'
```

Im trying to make the port become

```
port: "24081"
```

As you said, I change the single quote become double quotes as below

```
find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/def1/vars.yml -exec sed -i -e \"s/port:\${port}\$/port: \"\${port_https}\"/g\" {} \\;"
```

But when I try to run using jenkins,  the double quotes for port does not recognize. and become

```
port: 24081
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please start with a minimal example, both for testing on your own and for posting here. This is incredible hard to follow.

Comment: I assume that the reason is that there is no string interpolation within single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: @StephenKing I update my questions